# CSRF follies when trying to log in to Django with Python requests/sessions

Tags: django, authentication, csrf-token

I'm trying to log in to Django using Python requests. There are old questions about this, but none of them are answered due to inadequate details.

There are two CSRF tokens involved in this. One is the cookie, and the other is part of the login form. I've verified that Chrome returns the cookie token in the cookies and the form token in the body, and my url encoded body matches the format of one my browser passes back.

And yet I still get "Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)" as my response. Can any one suggest what I might be doing wrong?

My Python looks like this:

```
def login(url, username, password):
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get(f"{url}/accounts/login/")
    print(f"First headers: {response.headers}")
    header_csrftoken = session.cookies['csrftoken']
    print(f"Header csrftoken: {header_csrftoken}")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    form = soup.find("form", {"id":"login-form"})
    found = form.find("input", {"name":"csrfmiddlewaretoken"})
    form_csrftoken = found['value']
    print(f"csrftoken2: {form_csrftoken}")
    data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': form_csrftoken, 'username': username, 'password': password, 'next': '/'}

    response2 = session.post(f"{url}/accounts/login/", data=data, headers={'content-type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded'})
    print(f"outgoing: {response2.request.body}")
    print(f"Headers: {response2.request.headers}")


First headers: {'Date': 'Mon, 20 Sep 2021 03:37:17 GMT', 'Server': 'WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.8.12', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': 'Mon, 20 Sep 2021 03:37:17 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private', 'Vary': 'Cookie, Origin', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Content-Length': '20609', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Referrer-Policy': 'same-origin', 'Server-Timing': 'TimerPanel_utime;dur=16.402999999996837;desc="User CPU time", TimerPanel_stime;dur=3.0629999999973734;desc="System CPU time", TimerPanel_total;dur=19.46599999999421;desc="Total CPU time", TimerPanel_total_time;dur=21.546363830566406;desc="Elapsed time", SQLPanel_sql_time;dur=0;desc="SQL 0 queries", CachePanel_total_time;dur=0;desc="Cache 0 Calls"', 'Set-Cookie': 'csrftoken=FG9ronCxQUcIvT8iY79wF90CZjBKWFEhsB2sxVPYx4YQUZ5way1cHrazU46xk6Ig; expires=Mon, 19 Sep 2022 03:37:17 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax'}
Header csrftoken: FG9ronCxQUcIvT8iY79wF90CZjBKWFEhsB2sxVPYx4YQUZ5way1cHrazU46xk6Ig
form_csrftoken: 8a0D501NMPJXmcCJiwt7BiFhTyrzJhQLV5TEeyeetZv5LizXuXlNDAPeOjWm7IUK
outgoing: csrfmiddlewaretoken=8a0D501NMPJXmcCJiwt7BiFhTyrzJhQLV5TEeyeetZv5LizXuXlNDAPeOjWm7IUK&username=myname&password=naistrai&next=%2F
Outgoing Headers: {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.25.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'content-type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': 'csrftoken=FG9ronCxQUcIvT8iY79wF90CZjBKWFEhsB2sxVPYx4YQUZ5way1cHrazU46xk6Ig', 'Content-Length': '141'}
```

Comment: Do you use cache decorators on your views?

Comment: Yes, almost all of our interface entry points has a @never_cache decorator.

Comment: Do you use the cache middleware's then? Can you show your `MIDDLEWARE` setting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is intended or not, but when handing a POST request, it passes through django/middleware/csrf.py:CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view(). When it reaches this function, the POST data in the body isn't available via request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken'), so that function just returns an empty string.

This is probably intended because in this case, the csrf token in the body is the wrong one -- it's the form csrf token, not the header csrf token -- and this function wants to validate it against the header one.

What I had to do to fix this was to add 'X-CSRFToken': header_csrftoken to the headers of the POST.

Comment: That part is intended, the CSRF token needs to be posted to prevent CSRF attacks, what is weird is that you seem to have two different csrf tokens.

Comment: That part isn't so weird. There is one in the Cookies, and then a separate one as part of the login form. I can't tell you why they don't match.